# Is there any way to fetch the info of the current playing song?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am developing an app that mirrors the player state of third party player apps for studying reasons.

I managed to get to know how to control the other players playback state through the [`AudioManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager) API, but I'm clueless when it comes to know how to fetch any of the other players' current song info, like:

- song name;
- artist name, and;
- current song position.

Is there anything one can do to fetch this data from Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my research, I only found one way to do that but that unfortunately requires the device to be running **Android >= 21** (Lollipop) and a special permission from the user ([**`android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService))

It is possible to know which media is playing on the device using the [`MediaSessionManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager). To do that, all we need is to fetch the active [`MediaController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController)s in two ways:

- [`MediaSessionManager#getActiveSessions(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager#getActiveSessions(android.content.ComponentName)), and;
- [`MediaSessionManager#addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager#addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener(android.media.session.MediaSessionManager.OnActiveSessionsChangedListener,%20android.content.ComponentName)).

With the active `MediaController`s in hands, we can get the info we want from them through its available functions. It is good to point out that each player fills its Media Session data the way they want, so it's very possible that one has almost or no useful data at all, and another has a large amount of it (which is the case of the Google Play Music App).

Some functions of the `MediaController` class that we can highlight are:

- [`MediaController#getMetaData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController#getMetadata())
- [`MediaController#getPlayerState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController#getPlaybackState());
- [`MediaController#getQueue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController#getQueue()), and;
- [`MediaController#getQueueTitle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController#getQueueTitle()).

It is good to notice that players can put custom data into `MediaController#getMetaData` bundle. Google Play Music, for instance, adds two of them:

- `"com.google.android.music.mediasession.METADATA_KEY_QUEUE_SIZE"`, and;
- `"com.google.android.music.mediasession.METADATA_KEY_QUEUE_POSITION"`.

Debugging might be your best friend to get to know them.

---

Another fancy way to achieve that is through the use of [`MediaBrowserService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/media/MediaBrowserService). A detailed reading can be done in this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90).

---

If you know a better way to do this, specially if it does not require the `android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission, you are more than welcome to contribute :)

Comment: How to find out component which is required to pass to getActiveSessions()